# Iterate over an array of identical arrays and multiplying each subsequent element by x

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, math, iteration

I'm working through a problem that involves admirable numbers, which are defined as

> A number that is equal to the sum of all its proper divisors --
> provided that one of them is negative.
>
> For example, the proper divisors of 12 are 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, totaling
> 16. However, if 2 is negative, the total would be 12, the number itself. 12 is therefore an admirable number.
>
> 12 = 1 - 2 + 3 + 4 + 6

Essentially, I have to figure out what factor should be negative to get the admirable number.

I've worked through a similar problem that deals with [perfect numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number)
and am using a similar approach to figure solve this problem.  Basically, I start out by creating an array of factors for a number that doesn't include the number itself.   Then, I create an array of identical arrays that include all the factors for a number.

```
function admirable(n) {
  function factors(n) {
    let factors = []
      for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        if(n % i == 0) {
            factors.push(i);
        }
      }
      return factors
    }
  
  let arr = []
  for (let i=0; i<baseArr.length; i++) {
    arr.push(baseArr)
  }
  return arr
}
admirable(6) // [ [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
admirable(12) // [
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 ],
  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 ]
]
```

Once I've done this, I want to go through each array and multiply one number by -1, such that I get the result:

```
admirable(6) // [ [ -1, 2, 3 ], [ 1, -2, 3 ], [ 1, 2, -3 ] ]
admirable(12) // 
// [
//  [ -1, 2, 3, 4, 6 ],
//  [ 1, -2, 3, 4, 6 ],
//  [ 1, 2, -3, 4, 6 ],
//  [ 1, 2, 3, -4, 6 ],
//  [ 1, 2, 3, 4, -6 ]
// ]
```

Once I get the arrays in this configuration, I figure I can complete the last part of the problem:

> If n is admirable, return the proper divisor that must be rendered
> negative to make the sum of the proper divisors equal to n.

(I'll gladly accept any insight into ways to solve this part of the problem, too)

Is there a way to iterate over each array and make each subsequent number negative, e.g.

`arr[0][0] * -1, arr[1][1] * -1 ...arr[n][n] *-1` ?

I spent a lot of time working on this yesterday and couldn't get my brain around it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Your Question

If you have some array like this:

```
let arr = [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Then you can do:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  arr[i][i] *= -1;
}
```

Which gives

```
[[-1, 2, 3], [1, -2, 3], [1, 2, -3]]
```

### Alternatively...

Suppose you want to check if `n` is admirable. Let `s` be the sum of the divisors of `n` and `d` be a divisor of `n`. If you had computed `s` but made `d` negative, the total you would have obtained is `s - 2d`. So `n` is admirable if and only if `n = s - 2d` for some divisor `d` (and then `d` is the number you're looking for). So you can just check if `d = (s - n) / 2` is an integer and a divisor of `n`.

Comment: Perfect, I knew the solution to the array problem was just under my nose (I even allude to it in my question without realizing it).  Your alternate solution is very helpful, too!